# Php file wont execute properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

For a project someone send me this files but there are not executing properly (I think CSS is not working)

Files of the project:

[image: files of the project]

Page wrongly loaded:

[image: page wrongly loaded]

Start of my php code:

[image: start of my php code]

I tried to load the PHP file on Firefox, Google Chrome and Microsoft, and some of it loads, but it appears that some php tags doesn't work (it appears as plain text). I except it to create an array list with random values.

Comment: Are you running a web server and accessing the files using it (https://localhost/)?

Answer (score 1):

PHP files must be run on the server, not in the browser.
Try installing a local server like [xamp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).